# Auto Suggest ComboBox - MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, autocomplete, autosuggest

When I add to combobox the property `IsEditable="True"` it automatically receive the **"Auto Complete"** behavior.

Is there a way to add to this combobox the "Auto Suggest" behavior?

I mean, when writing in the combobox opens a list of options with the above caption.

**(If possible = without destroying the MVVM)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

I tried to add the auto suggest kind of behavior using standard combobox and animation

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBoxItem>Orange</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Apple</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Banana</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Cherry</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBox.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBoxBase.TextChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsDropDownOpen">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ComboBox.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

Give this a try and let me know if this is what you are looking for, more sophisticated behavior might need some extra efforts

**Add suggestion filter for combo Items**

xaml

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}"
            Text="{Binding ComboText,Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <ComboBox.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBoxBase.TextChanged">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsDropDownOpen">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True"
                                                    KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ComboBox.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

view model

```cs
public ICollectionView ComboItems{ get; set; }

public string ComboText
{
    get
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    set
    {
        ComboItems.Filter = item => item.ToString().ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower());
    }
}
```

you may need to filter based on your items types, above is for string values

to init the ComboItems

```cs
var myItems = new[] { "Apple", "Orange", "Cherry", "Banana" };
ComboItems = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myItems);
```

replace my items with your collection

Comment: I'm looking for auto suggest, it's mean any time you add text the combobox open with the suggestes that filter by the text that you wrote.

Comment: so do you forward the combo list to be filtered also? you may perhaps share some screen for more details.

Comment: Since setting IsEditable enables the similar behavior so IsTextSearchEnable will be redundant to same. this is primary reason why it is not available for ComboBox. IsTextSearchEnable works for those items control which do not have an integrated TextBox for such purpose, eg ListBox, ItemsControl etc.

Comment: There a way to cancel the auto complete?

Comment: this is where you can use IsTextSearchEnable and set it to false to disable the auto complete, eg IsTextSearchEnabled="False"

Comment: but how did i integrate, if i got SelectedValuePath="Id" and Text="Name" ?

Comment: @ColonelSoftware, following is line you need to work with. Currently assuming a string object. ComboItems.Filter = item => item.ToString().ToLower().Contains(value.ToLower());